# When I press command key text gets highlighted and enlarged - how do I remove this features (disable Enable Hover Text)?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, keybindings, accessibility

When I press command the text in my mac becomes large. I've tried googling how to remove it and in system preferences too! How do I remove this?

Also, I can't even take a screen shot because it interacts with my screen shot keyboard strokes! In other words, if I try to take a screen shot it stops making the text large. So I can't take a screen shot.

This happened when I set up my new mac book m1...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you might have The "Enable Hover Text" option enabled.

System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Zoom -> Uncheck "Enable Hover Text"

Hope this helps
[image]